# Holder inequality, Lp and Lq spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

Let $1 \leq p \leq q \leq +\infty$ real such as $1/p+1/q=1$. We have $f_n, f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $g_n, g \in L^q(\mathbb{R})$ such as $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^p$ and $g_n \rightarrow g$ in $L^q$. I would like to prove that $f_n g_n \rightarrow fg$ in $L^1$.

I wrote that $f_n g_n \in L^1$ and $||f_n g_n||_1 \leq ||f_n||_p ||g_n||_q$ by Hölder inequality. Similarly, $fg \in L^1$ and $||fg||_1 \leq ||f||_p ||g||_q$.

$||f_n||_p \rightarrow ||f||_p$ and $||g_n||_q \rightarrow ||g||_q$ but despite all these elements, I can't prove that $||f_n g_n - fg||_1 \rightarrow 0$. Someone could help me ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the fact that $||f_n-f||_p$ and $||g_n-g||_q$ both converge to $0$. Then so does their product. Use the Hoelder inequality to deduce that $|(f_n-f)(g_n-g)|$ converges to $0$ in $L^1$ and take the integrand apart with the triangle inequality.

Comment: This uses the same little trick as when you're showing any other sort of multiplication is jointly continuous: $f_ng_n-fg=(f_n-f)g_n+f(g_n-g)$.

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus I don't see how taking that apart with the triangle inequality leads to what we want... In fact I don't see how it leads to $f_ng_n-fg$ at all, regardless of why the other terms should tend to zero.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I should have written it all down before commenting...

Comment: Thank you, thank you, I found :-)